# Update field of MYSQL Table depending upon values in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have two table in my SQL Database
One is Companies & Another is Company_advertisements.
I want to update field of company table "adv"

```
SET Company.adv = 1 if Company_adv.image is not empty
SET Company.adv = 0 if Company_adv.image is empty
```

The foreign key for Company_adv table is company_id

I tried using the following syntax but it didn't worked.Instead after running this query all the values of Companmy.adv become 1 after that

I tried this query:

```
UPDATE companies cmp, company_adv cma 
SET    cmp.adv=1 
WHERE  cma.company_id=cmp.id AND 
       cma.image1 IS NOT NULL
```

Please help me !!

Comment: You need to use a `JOIN`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if that's the case, you need to use `LEFT JOIN`

```
UPDATE  companies cmp
        LEFT JOIN company_adv cma
            ON cmp.id = cma.company_id
SET     cmp.adv = IF(cma.image1 IS NULL, 0, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer I tried doing it but same result all the values are becoming 1 even if cma.image1 is a null value.

Comment: It is showing some error MYSQL lost connection...Please check the version :Software version: 5.5.28-cll - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Comment: oh.. i think the lost connection  has nothing to do with the query. but wait. do you have index on the id's? eg primary key?

Comment: yes...id is the primary key for Company table & company_id is the primary key for company_adv

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
UPDATE companies
   SET adv=IF((SELECT image
                 FROM company_adv
                WHERE companies.id=company_adv.company_id) IS NULL,
              0,
              1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but still i am getting the following error :#2013 - Lost connection to MySQL server during query and all the values becoming 1 whether image1 is empty or not.

Comment: Could you attach schema creation DQL and data insertion SQL to your question, please? Then I'll be able to recreate your case.

Comment: Thanks a lot all of you....I solved it..Here's the query       UPDATE  companies cmp
        LEFT JOIN company_adv cma
            ON cmp.id = cma.company_id
SET     cmp.adv = IF(cma.image1 LIKE '% %', 0, 1)

Comment: @Ferhat: could you, please, post it as an answer and accept it?